# No auth token on service query even after success login

Tags: vuex, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, feathersjs

I have a setup of nuxtjs ssr using [vuex featherjs recommended example](https://vuex.feathersjs.com/common-patterns.html#full-nuxt-example), feathersjs as the api.

Authentication using JWT & Local strategy works, I receive the access token
but querying user service using nuxtjs gives me an error.

```
ERROR NotAuthenticated

{type: "FeathersError", name: "NotAuthenticated", message: "No auth token", code: 401, className: "not-authenticated", …}
```

Querying using postman works but querying using nuxtjs returns the message *No auth token*.

I have already opened a ticket on [github repo](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-vuex/issues/458).

Comment: Is the token included into the header of your request using nuxt?

Comment: You don't attach header in socket.io

Comment: What are you talking about? Regardless of the fact that it is possible to set extra headers in socket.io, you need to be sure, that the server you are requesting receives your authentication token. Otherwise it cannot verify, if you are allowed to use its service. It doesn't matter which library you use.

Comment: pardon me, cookie was added to the header request

Cookie: feathers-jwt=eyJhb*****